# Copying rows from two or more Excel sheets to another based on cell value

Tags: excel, vba

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I1tUF.png)I don't think that could match the mines, anyway,

The difference is copying from more than one sheet to another based on a cell value and not do it with macro VBA but with:

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range).
```

In fact I tried this but it doesn't give a good result:

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
    For Each Sh In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
        If Not Sh.Name = "Archive" Then
            If Cells(Target.Row, 3) = "delivered" Then Cells(Target.Row, 3).EntireRow.Copy Sheets("Archive").Range("A" & Rows.Count) _
              .End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
        End If 
    Next Sh
End Sub
```

Thank's for helping me.

Comment: *"doesn't give a good result"* is no error description at all. What is wrong with your code? Please tell which errors you get and where. Or what your code does instead of what you expect it to do. *"copying from more than one sheet to another based on a cell value"* is a bit too vague. Reading [ask] and [mcve] might help to improve your question also data examples or screenshots can help a lot.

Comment: My example include three sheets with the same four columns name : Name - Task No - Status - Remarks, two of theme contained data named "project1" and "project2". the copying data should be from these two sheets to the theird named "Archive". The problem is : thetransfered data was made with duplicates.

Comment: I do want put the file here but I don't know how.

Comment: Try: Instead of your loop `For Each Sh In ThisWorkbook.Sheets` (remove it) just use `sh` everywhere like `sh.Cells(Target.Row, 3)`. If it doesn't help: *"thetransfered data was made with duplicates."* is very unspecific. I think you need a way more that what fits into a comment to explain that properly. [Edit] your question to add eg screenshots of how it *actually* looks like and how it *should* look like. That would help a lot. • Note that we don't accept files here.

Comment: Thank's, but there are still duplicates copied data but less

Comment: and still you didn't do what I asked for in the comments. Can't help anymore, too less information.

Comment: I put image but I don't know if I success

Answer (score 0):

I post herewith the solution of my question, thank you PEH and thank's for the forum member.

Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
If Not Sh.Name = "Archive" Then
lastcolumn = Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
If Sh.Cells(Target.Row, 3) = "delivered" And Sh.Cells(Target.Row, lastcolumn) <> "" Then
Range(Cells(Target.Row, 1), Cells(Target.Row, lastcolumn)).Copy _
Sheets("Archive").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
End If
End If
End Sub